# How can I develop Image recognition program

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mfc

My program will recognize the advertisement between each TV Programs.
But I don't know how to recognize the ads.
I had Sound Recognition in mind but It's so difficult.
I'm using FFmpeg Library. 
There is VideoState struct Reference.

```
typedef struct VideoState {
SDL_Thread *read_tid;
SDL_Thread *video_tid;
SDL_Thread *refresh_tid;
AVInputFormat *iformat;
int no_background;
int abort_request;
int force_refresh;
int paused;
int last_paused;
int que_attachments_req;
int seek_req;
int seek_flags;
int64_t seek_pos;
int64_t seek_rel;
int read_pause_return;
AVFormatContext *ic;

int audio_stream;

int av_sync_type;
double external_clock; /* external clock base */
int64_t external_clock_time;

double audio_clock;
double audio_diff_cum; /* used for AV difference average computation */
double audio_diff_avg_coef;
double audio_diff_threshold;
int audio_diff_avg_count;
AVStream *audio_st;
PacketQueue audioq;
int audio_hw_buf_size;
DECLARE_ALIGNED(16,uint8_t,audio_buf2)[AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE * 4];
uint8_t silence_buf[SDL_AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE];
uint8_t *audio_buf;
uint8_t *audio_buf1;
unsigned int audio_buf_size; /* in bytes */
int audio_buf_index; /* in bytes */
int audio_write_buf_size;
AVPacket audio_pkt_temp;
AVPacket audio_pkt;
struct AudioParams audio_src;
struct AudioParams audio_tgt;
struct SwrContext *swr_ctx;
double audio_current_pts;
double audio_current_pts_drift;
int frame_drops_early;
int frame_drops_late;
AVFrame *frame;

enum ShowMode {
    SHOW_MODE_NONE = -1, SHOW_MODE_VIDEO = 0, SHOW_MODE_WAVES, 
SHOW_MODE_RDFT, SHOW_MODE_NB
} show_mode;
int16_t sample_array[SAMPLE_ARRAY_SIZE];
int sample_array_index;
int last_i_start;
RDFTContext *rdft;
int rdft_bits;
FFTSample *rdft_data;
int xpos;

SDL_Thread *subtitle_tid;
int subtitle_stream;
int subtitle_stream_changed;
AVStream *subtitle_st;
PacketQueue subtitleq;
SubPicture subpq[SUBPICTURE_QUEUE_SIZE];
int subpq_size, subpq_rindex, subpq_windex;
SDL_mutex *subpq_mutex;
SDL_cond *subpq_cond;

double frame_timer;
double frame_last_pts;
double frame_last_duration;
double frame_last_dropped_pts;
double frame_last_returned_time;
double frame_last_filter_delay;
int64_t frame_last_dropped_pos;
double video_clock;                          ///< pts of last decoded frame 
/ predicted pts of next decoded frame
int video_stream;
AVStream *video_st;
PacketQueue videoq;
double video_current_pts;                    ///< current displayed pts 
(different from video_clock if frame fifos are used)
double video_current_pts_drift;              ///< video_current_pts - time 
(av_gettime) at which we updated video_current_pts - used to have running 
video pts
int64_t video_current_pos;                   ///< current displayed file pos
VideoPicture pictq[VIDEO_PICTURE_QUEUE_SIZE];
int pictq_size, pictq_rindex, pictq_windex;
SDL_mutex *pictq_mutex;
SDL_cond *pictq_cond;
#if !CONFIG_AVFILTER
struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx;
#endif

char filename[1024];
int width, height, xleft, ytop;
int step;

#if CONFIG_AVFILTER
AVFilterContext *in_video_filter;           ///< the first filter in the 
video chain
AVFilterContext *out_video_filter;          ///< the last filter in the 
video chain
int use_dr1;
FrameBuffer *buffer_pool;
#endif

int refresh;
int last_video_stream, last_audio_stream, last_subtitle_stream;

SDL_cond *continue_read_thread;

enum V_Show_Mode v_show_mode;
} VideoState;
```

What can I use for My Program.... I really need your help.. Thank you!!!

Comment: try OpenCV: http://opencv.org

Comment: This sounds like an enormously ambitious project. Rather than writing code you should be doing feasibility analysis,

Comment: What makes you think image recognition will be any easier than audio? Do you have static images that delimit the ad breaks?

Comment: I want to know whether the videostate structure has the appropriate variables I want. 
In any field, including voice or video, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use of Proper Image Processing/ Computer Vision libraries:

**FFmpeg library is used for changing properties like (fps, bit-rate, sampling rate, codec etc) of videos and audios, but for the task you've mentioned here you've to use some dedicated image processing or computer vision library**

- There are few options you can go for, like Matlab's image processing library, Java based (ImageJ and OpenIMAJ) and Opencv (in C/C++ and python).
- The best option for you would be OpenCV, because its a complete computer vision library, it has built-in features which are ready to use, you can easily use them without any need of knowing the background details of all those algorithms.
- In OpenCV there are videoio and video analysis libraries which can be helpful for you, and also OpenCV is written in C++ for which you won't need to worry about the optimization of these algorithms because they are already optimized and as you will be dealing with continuous video streams you would not want your program to slow down while processing.

I hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!! I have more questions. I want to know whether the videostate structure has the appropriate variables I want. 
In any field, including voice or video, etc...